# Automatically mount partition when needed

Tags: unix, shell, mount

Can anyone suggest a method of mounting a partition (e.g. an NFS share) when a user changes into the directory it is set to be mounted to, and not on the system startup?

So far I've been unable to propose such a method, aside from editing BASH built-in **cd** implementation and forcing an fstab/mtab check before the working directory is actually changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.linux-consulting.com/Amd_AutoFS/autofs-3.html#ss3.1 <-- That's what you want to use.

Comment: +1 for autofs.  I like the docs at http://www.autofs.org/ better though.